# How do i obtain only the first principal component in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dimensionality-reduction

For certain measurements i need to obtain only the numeric value of the first principal component from the matrix. Can someone please tell me how do i go about it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths


Comment: Have you tried to search for an answer before asking? There's a multitude of questions (with good answers!) even here in SO, *e.g* [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402110/principal-component-analysis-in-matlab) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688312/matlab-pca-analysis-and-reconstruction-of-multi-dimensional-data)...

Comment: @MitchWheat, given that this is a MATLAB question, I would think this counts as the programming question "which MATLAB commands should I use to achieve this" rather than the maths question "how do I calculate principal components".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most straight forward way is just to get the top eigenvector/value of your data's covariance matrix using `eigs`

say the data matrix `x` is N by D, or # of data by dimension of data

you can simply do

```
C = cov(X);
[V, D] = eigs(C, 1);
```

in fact, you can get the top `k` principal components by running

```
[V, D] = eigs(C, k);
```

Comment: Prgao,I had used "eig" which gives dimension error if used like eig(C,k), but had missed out on the "eigs" prior to your post. Thank you so much it worked as desired.