# How to find projection matrix for PCA in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-mining, projection, pca

I'm trying to reduce the dimensionality of my data with PCA.

So I call `[COEFF, SCORE] = princomp(data);` According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689269/2483127), I can reconstruct my data with `SCORE * COEFF' + Mean`, and it works.

But I'm trying to find the projection matrix `P`, where any given vector `x` can be transformed to its projection in PCA space.

My intuition tells me that I should be able to project `x` by :

```
proj = ((x-m) * inv(C)) + m
```

where `m` is the mean of my data.

so I test this by choosing `x` as the first observation of my data, and I expect `proj` should be very close to the first row of `SCORE`. However this is not the case.

So where am I doing wrong? And how can I find the projection matrix?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, now I see my mistake.

First of all, COEFF is orthogonal (not sure) so `inv(COEFF) == COEFF'`

and the projection is found by

```
proj = COEFF' * (x-m)
```